# ¿Como obtener el texto de option y luego extraer un número?

Tags: javascript, html, select, options

Tengo el siguiente `<select>` lo que quiero hacer es agarrar/obtener el texto que contiene y de ser posible el valor numérico.

```html
   <select name="select" id="comprar-js">
            <option value="show1">PLATEA (450$)</option>
            <option value="show2">CAMPO (800$)</option>
            <option value="show3">ESCENARIO (1000$)</option>
            <option value="shoW4">BANDEJA (3000$)</option>
        </select>
```

Quiero acceder al texto que contiene cada `<option>` (PLATEA (450$)) y una vez que lo obtengo usar el valor de numero que tiene para realizar operaciones.

Comment: Tienes algún conocimiento de Javascript | JQuery?

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacerlo con la siguiente línea

```
document.getElementById('comprar-js').options[document.getElementById('comprar-js').selectedIndex].text;
```

`document.getElementById('comprar-js').options` devuelve el array de opciones y `document.getElementById('comprar-js').selectedIndex` devuelve el índice seleccionado del array.

Te recomiendo que utilices los atributos data- para facilitar el acceso a información extra. Por ejemplo

```
<select name="select" id="comprar-js">
            <option data-valor="450" value="show1">PLATEA (450$)</option>
            <option data-valor="800" value="sho2">CAMPO (800$)</option>
            <option data-valor="1000" value="show3">ESCENARIO (1000$)</option>
            <option data-valor="3000" value="shoW4">BANDEJA (3000$)</option>
</select>
```

Y modificando el código anterior podemos acceder al valor con:

```
let valorEntrada =  document.getElementById('comprar-js').options[document.getElementById('comprar-js').selectedIndex].dataset.valor;
```

Acá puedes encontrar más información sobre los atributos data https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos

Comment: Usar `dataset` también es una buena opción.

Answer (score 3):

Ambas cosas se pueden realizar, la primera se realiza iterando cada opción dentro del `select`, la segunda la haremos por medio de expresiones regulares, dejo explicación detallada en el código:

```js
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/; //Este será nuestro factor de búsqueda

$("select option").each(function(){ //Iteramos cada opción del select
    text = $(this).text(); //Capturamos el texto de cada opción
    value = regExp.exec(text); //Por medio de una expresión regular capturamos el valor dentro de paréntesis, esto nos genera un array de dos posiciones, el índice 0 será el valor aún dentro del paréntesis, el índice 1 será el valor sin símbolos.
    console.log("Array de valores capturados", value);
    console.log("Valor sin paréntesis", value[1]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="select" id="comprar-js">
  <option value="show1">PLATEA (450$)</option>
  <option value="sho2">CAMPO (800$)</option>
  <option value="show3">ESCENARIO (1000$)</option>
  <option value="shoW4">BANDEJA (3000$)</option>
</select>
```

> Importante destacar que el código utiliza JQuery, también se podría realizar con JS puro.

Comment: No es necesario usar expresiones regulares, con un simple substring puedes obtener el valor numérico

Comment: Sabemos que en ocasiones hay múltiples formas de realizar un proceso, esta es la que domino y he preferido.

Comment: El método para hacerlo con jquery es correcto, pero usar regex no creo que sea lo mas adecuado al ser algo complicado, es mejor buscar alternativas mas simples.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el texto de un `<option>` con javascript puedes hacer lo siguiente; primero obtienes el elemento `<select>`, luego en este obtienes el option seleccionado del array de opciones con `options[combo.selectedIndex]` para luego obtener el texto con `.text`.

Luego para obtener el número del texto puedes quitar el texto con `split()`, dividiéndolo por los paréntesis y así poder hacer operaciones con el número:

```js
function obtener(){
  //para obtener el texto
  combo = document.getElementById("comprar-js");
  texto = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(texto); 
  //para obtener el numero y hacer operaciones
  numero=(texto.split("(")[1].split("$)")[0]);
  console.log(numero*5);
}
```

```html
<select name="select" id="comprar-js">
            <option value="show1">PLATEA (450$)</option>
            <option value="show2">CAMPO (800$)</option>
            <option value="show3">ESCENARIO (1000$)</option>
            <option value="shoW4">BANDEJA (3000$)</option>
        </select>
        
        <br>
        <button onclick="obtener()">Obtener</button>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.